# How is this code return at -2 to 2 number?

Tags: javascript

How can this return a number between -2 and 2

```
var number = Math.random() * 4 - 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

The method [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) gives you a decimal number between 0 and 1. If it returns, 0.00001, you'll get `0.00001 * 4 - 2 = 0.00004 - 2 = -1.99996`

> A pseudo-random number in the range 0 to less than 1 (inclusive of 0, but not 1) with approximately uniform distribution over that range — which you can then scale to your desired range.